# vb.net send outlook email using smtp and outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate

Tags: outlook, smtp, vb.net-2010

I would like to send an email using an SMTP server and an Outlook template as the mail message.

```
Dim application As New Outlook.Application
Dim path As String = "S:\TCM\Vendor.oft"

' Create a new MailItem and set the To, Subject, and Body properties.
Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(application.CreateItemFromTemplate(path), Outlook.MailItem)

Dim mail As MailMessage = DirectCast(newMail, MailMessage)
```

I am trying to create a mail item from a template and cast that to a `MailMessage` so I can use an SMTP server to send the email. However, I get the following error.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'.
>
> Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct conversion between `MailMessage` from BCL and Outlook's `MailItem`. You can send the MailItem from a different account in Outlook by setting the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property which allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

You may find the [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Outlook.MailItem` obviously known nothing about the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` object.

It is your responsibility to convert an Outlook message to a MIME message and/or explicitly populate all MailMessage properties before sending it.